# How does odoo decide if a field is importable

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have the following field that I added to the model

```python
import_action = fields.Selection([('none','None'),('confirm','Confirm'),('ship','Ship')],
               'Import Action',
               default='none', 
               required=False, 
               readonly=True,
               select=False,
               selectable=False, 
               invisible=True)
```

I need to be able to import this field. Or, for some reasons, odoo consider it as not-importable.

Can someone explain on what criteria odoo based itself to decide if a field is importable or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests, and here are my conclusions.

You can only import fields which are not `readonly`.

All `readonly="True"` fields are automaticaly set to non-importable.